# Как в create react app возвращать статус 404 при обращении к несуществующей странице?

Tags: reactjs

Ребята, приветствую ) сориентируйте плиз в какую сторону смотреть, где можно подглядеть нормальный мануал или пример ? В общем в create react app нужно возвращать статус 404 при обращении к несуществующей странице.  Пробовал прикрутить express , но не понял как можно конфигугировать под свою задачу . в документации https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/server-rendering не сильно понял как настроить сервер и роутинг ( может есть нормальные примеры или статьи где можно подсмотреть примеры реализации ? заранее спасибо.